# WPF custom Button using Geometry from resource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

Is there a way to use a collection of PathGeometry like these:

Path 1
F1 M 170.255,178.837L 170.255,221.158C 170.255,228.917 164.174,230.777 156.745,225.286L 136.003,209.973C 128.572,204.488 128.572,195.512 136.003,190.023L 156.745,174.706C 164.174,169.217 170.255,171.079 170.255,178.837 Z

Path 2
F1 M 152.29,174.464L 134.314,187.734C 129.978,190.937 127.589,195.29 127.589,199.994C 127.589,204.7 129.978,209.057 134.314,212.26L 152.29,225.531C 150.333,229.378 145.412,229.52 139.678,225.286L 118.935,209.973C 111.506,204.489 111.506,195.512 118.935,190.022L 139.678,174.708C 145.412,170.475 150.333,170.617 152.29,174.464 Z

and use them to make a custom button in the same way you can make a circular button shown in this example?
http://www.wpftutorial.net/Templates.html

The example involves overriding the control template and it seems a lot of work if I want to have many custom-shaped buttons. And what if I want to load the geometry points from the resource?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No problems, this code goes into Resources.

```
<Geometry x:Key="geo">
        M 152.29,174.464L 134.314,187.734C 129.978,190.937 127.589,195.29 127.589,199.994C 127.589,204.7 129.978,209.057 134.314,212.26L 152.29,225.531C 150.333,229.378 145.412,229.52 139.678,225.286L 118.935,209.973C 111.506,204.489 111.506,195.512 118.935,190.022L 139.678,174.708C 145.412,170.475 150.333,170.617 152.29,174.464 Z
</Geometry>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Path Data="{StaticResource geo}" Fill="HotPink" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: had to make a small adjustment to use the StreamGeometry instead as Geometry is an abstract class so can't use it there but works on the large, thanks!