# How to make circle button in XAML and C# with customize style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, geometry

I am new in XAML and I have a problem with my button in my simple game. 
I make a circle button and I need to change it's color, but my button doesn't give the default style of a button like animate, pointer change on hover it, click animate and etc, also it's color doesn't change.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RedColorXX" Color="Red" />
</Page.Resources>

<Button x:Name="btnRed" Style="{StaticResource  btnColor}" Content="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="228" Margin="62,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="228" Background="#FFCA6969" Click="colors_Click" FontSize="0.01" BorderBrush="Azure" Grid.Column="1" >
    <Button.Template >
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" >
            <Grid >
                <Path Stretch="Uniform" UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FFCA6969">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

and the color change code that dosen't work !

```
btnRed.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["RedColorXX"];
```

Comment: Your click needs to change the color of your ellipse. Try this inside the ellipse Fill="{Binding ElementName=btnRed, Path=Background}"

Comment: You can copy a version of the [default Button template from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328(v=vs.100).aspx), then just modify the ControlTemplate to what you have here. That should give you all the default behaviors, with your own custom shape for it.

Comment: He'll need to change his `Fill` to `{TemplateBinding Background}` when doing so but that's definitely the best route.

Comment: It is, frankly, not very clear what you're asking here. You write _"I need to change its color"_, but don't explain when or why you want the color to change. You seem to be asking how to preserve existing behavior of the `Button` object, but it's not clear how you want the "existing behavior" to interact with the "change its color" aspect. Please provide a good [mcve] showing exactly what you've tried, with a precise, clear explanation of what that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: In the meantime, look at these related (possibly duplicate) questions concerning custom buttons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633662/how-do-i-make-a-button-shape-a-custom-path-in-wpf, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118861/change-shape-of-wpf-button-without-changing-other-styles, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734825/custom-button-template-in-wpf, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706543/creating-a-button-template, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453458/wpf-custom-button-using-geometry-from-resource

Comment: And of course https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwpf%5D+custom+button+template and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwpf%5D+custom+button+shape

Answer (score 2):

For example I turn your fill="#FFCA6969" into yellow:

```
<Button x:Name="btnRed"  Content="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="228" Margin="100,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="228" Background="#FFCA6969" Click="colors_Click" FontSize="0.01" BorderBrush="Azure" >
        <Button.Template >
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" >
                <Grid >
                    <Path Stretch="Uniform" UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="Yellow">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Comment: This definitely works... I however tweaked it a bit to achieve what it was that I wanted.